# Adding Custom tab to product page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, phtml, tabs

Im looking to add a custom tab to the bottom of my existing tabs found on this page: [Example](https://www.onyxmenswear.co.uk/brave-soul-aberdeen-mens-ripstop-fur-hooded-parka.html)

I don't mind the way i add it, the information that's going to be added there will be the same information throughout the whole website it will be a delivery-information tab which just states all the delivery information. I was thinking either making an attribute and controlling it that way or injecting it directly. I would love to hear anyone's advice and their help.

Kindest Regards

bLAZYY

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's `local.xml` file, add the following:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="delivery_information" template="catalog/product/view/delivery_information.phtml">
      <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
      <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Delivery Information</value></action>
    </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This creates a "Delivery Information" tab which calls a custom template (*more on this below*).

You'll then need to ensure that said custom template exists:

> app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/catalog/product/view/delivery_information.phtml

From there, you can freely modify the contents of this template; either call an attribute or CMS/Static Block (*recommended if your Delivery Information isn't likely to change on a per-product basis*), for example:

```
<?php echo = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery_information'); ?>
```

Then create a CMS/Static Block with the **Identifier** as "delivery_information".

Comment: I dont have a local.xml file in my theme 

i've navigated to 

public_html/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout

Comment: From what i can see the theme uses the catalog.xml file to pull in the tab? so i put it in there instead and its not worked

Comment: Create a `local.xml` file in your theme, and wrap the above code in `<layout version="0.1.0"></layout>` tags and it will work.